# Getting an access token for a local Facebook script

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I will start this question by mentioning that this is my first experience with Facebook's API.

I have a script on my own PC, which is executed with WAMP. It fetches data from Facebook's Graph API, **when given manually an access token from [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)**, getting a specific group's feed.

I would like my script to ask for an access token, and then just use `file_get_contents` to ask for the **json string**. I need the access token to have all the permissions available.

What should I do to make the next steps work?

1. Open my PHP file. (already exists)
2. The script will ask for an access token.
3. It will print the content of `https://graph.facebook.com/GROUP_ID/feed?=access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are developing a **facebook app**, you don't need to login to facebook again. (Code snippets for both PHP and Javascript, use that is required to you.)

   **[PHP]**

   You can get the access_token by performing Http GET request on -

   ```
   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials
   ```

   For more details: [login as app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/#step1)

   **[Javascript]**

   ```
   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) 
   {
     if (response.status === 'connected') 
     {
         var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
         var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
     } 
     else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
     {
        // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
        // but has not authenticated your app
     } 
     else 
     {
        // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
     }
   });
   ```

   For more details: [getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)
2. If you are **integrating fb with your website**, you need to login first and in the response you can obtain the access token.

   Read this: [Login Architecture](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture/)

   **[PHP]** (Difficulty: High)

   Read this: [server-side-login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/)

   **[Javascript]** (Dfifficulty: Low)

   ```
   FB.login(function(response) 
   {
       if (response.authResponse)
       {
           console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
           var access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
       } 
       else 
       {
           console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
       }
    });
   ```

   More details: [FB.Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/#step4)

Comment: I asked the poster of another answer as well- Am I able to automate the process of getting OAuth access token, by providing my own user details?

Comment: Why do you want that, and what exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for server-side authentication. There is [detailed documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/) about this subject.

Comment: Is the login dialog a must?

Comment: If you are integrating fb-api in a website, the login is must. Else not.

Comment: Can't I provide my fb email and password, for example? To automate the process.

Comment: No, that is not possible. Facebook does not want apps handling passwords, that's a security risk. You must use the dialog.